# Добавление текста в MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь добавить в базу:

```
<textarea name="comment" placeholder="текст" rows="5"></textarea>

$comment = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['comment'])), 0, 2000);
```

вылетает ошибка:

*Notice: Undefined index: comment in W:\domains\eventfactory.ua\php\order.php on line 52*

поменял строку на:

```
$comment = substr(htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['comment'])), 0, 2000);
```

ошибка исчезла, но столбец **comment** не заполняется в базе, в отличии от **name**, **tel** и **email**.

пример кода:

```
<?php
    ###
    #   Подключение к бд
class mysql {
    ###
    #   Подключение к бд

    function connect($db_host, $db_login, $db_passwd, $db_name) {
        mysql_connect($db_host, $db_login, $db_passwd) or die ("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error()); //~ устанавливаем подключение с бд
        mysql_query("set names utf8") or die ("<br>Invalid query: " . mysql_error()); //~ указываем что передаем данные в utf8
        mysql_select_db($db_name) or die ("<br>Invalid query: " . mysql_error()); //~ выбираем базу данных

    }
}


function query($query, $type, $num) {
        if ($q=mysql_query($query)) {
            switch ($type) {
                case 'num_row' : return mysql_num_rows($q); break;
                case 'result' : return mysql_result($q, $num); break;
                case 'accos' : return mysql_fetch_assoc($q); break;
                case 'none' : return $q;
                default: return $q;
            }
        }   
    }

    $db_host = '127.0.0.1';
    $db_login = 'login';
    $db_passwd = 'pass';
    $db_name = 'name';

    ###
    #   экранирование данных 
    function screening($data) {
        $data = trim($data); //~ удаление пробелов из начала и конца строки
        return mysql_real_escape_string($data); //~ экранирование символов
    }

$db = new mysql(); //~ Создаем новый объект класса
$db -> connect($db_host, $db_login, $db_passwd, $db_name);

    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    error_reporting(-1);   

if(!empty($_POST['send'])) {

    $name = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name'])), 0, 300);
    $tel = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['tel'])), 0, 100);
    $email = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email'])), 0, 100);
    $comment = substr(htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['comment'])), 0, 2000);


    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $Nzakaz = rand(10000, 99999);

    $mess  = "Имя: <b>".$name."</b><br />";
    $mess .= "Телефон: <b>".$tel."</b><br />";
    $mess .= "E-mail: <b>".$email."</b><br />";
    $mess .= "Комментарий: <b>".$comment."</b><br />";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $theme = "Заявка Z".$Nzakaz;

    mail("my@mail.ru", $theme, $mess, "From: gr.ua <gr@gmail.com>\nContent-Type: text/html;\n charset=utf-8\nX-Priority: 0");

    //Добавляем данные в БД
    $query = "INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('$Nzakaz', '$name', '$tel', '$email', '$comment')";
        mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    }



  if($query = true){
    echo "<h3>Заявка удачно оформлена.</h3>";
    echo "<p>Заявке присвоен номер Z".$Nzakaz.". Наш менеджер свяжется с вами в ближайшее время.</p>";
    exit();
    }else {

    echo "<h2>Ошибка! Попробуйте еще раз.</h2>";
    exit();
}


?>
```

Comment: я не спец в пыхе ...но по моему пора уже уходить на mysqli или вообще pdo, new mysql()  экземпляр которого не существует наверно ... что тто я не помню что бы в mysql экземпляр класса объявляли ...

Comment: а зачем вам  вообще такая конструкция substr(htmlspecialchars(isset($_POST['comment'])), 0, 2000); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для версий PHP ниже 7:

```
$comment = isset($_POST['comment']) ? $_POST['comment'] : '';
$comment = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($comment)), 0, 2000);
```

Для 7 и выше:

```
$comment = $_POST['comment'] ?? '';
$comment = substr(htmlspecialchars(trim($comment)), 0, 2000);
```

Судя по `mysql_query`, у вас ниже 7